# JavaScript: check if a css rule is applied to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to find out if a css rule (a string) is applied to a particular element on the page? For example:

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li id="item">I want to check this element</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.list > li { color: red; }
```

JS:

```
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var rule = '.list > li';
isRuleApplied(rule, item);

function isRuleApplied(rule, item) {
    // ???
    // returns true if rule matches the item, false otherwise
}
```

[Edit]
There used be a special function in WebKit/Blink that returned all the matched rules for the element - `window.getMatchedCSSRules(node)` - but it was deprecated and no longer works.

Is there any better way than looping through all the selectors and checking if they match the element? Also, this way still doesn't allow you to check for :hover state easily, etc.

Comment: Haha, nice one! But obviously my problem is that I don't know what to put there or whether it is even possible.

Comment: Not sure this is possible in the way you want. you can check if an element matches a selector, you can use js to get the applied styles. However, you'd need to parse the css to find out if the styles set in the css file match the styles applied to the element. otherwise you are giving the selector and rule in the js. you'd effectively be testing the js functionality rather then the css application

Comment: @susheel, unfortunately that function is no longer supported (I updated the question)

Comment: @YemSalat We are not here to write all the code for you. We can help you if you are stuck somewhere, but please at least try a few things on your own and do some research *before* coming here.

Comment: @DarkAshelin that's exactly what I did, see edits to the original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Element.matches` || `Element.matchesSelector`

Adapting [MDN reference with Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) (for cross-browser support):

```
  function isRuleApplied(element,selector) {

      if(typeof element.matches == 'function')
           return element.matches(selector);

      if(typeof element.matchesSelector == 'function')
           return element.matchesSelector(selector);

      var matches = (element.document || element.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(selector);
      var i = 0;

      while (matches[i] && matches[i] !== element)
        i++;

     return matches[i] ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! I'd rather use native code then loop through all selectors every time (looping is still good enough as a fallback though)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find all elements that match the rule, then check if the result contains the desired element:

```js
function isRuleApplied(rule, element) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(rule), i;
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i] === element) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(isRuleApplied(".list > li", document.getElementById("item1"))); // true
console.log(isRuleApplied(".list > li", document.getElementById("item2"))); // false
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li id="item1">Match this</li>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
  <li id="item2">But not this</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), element) !== -1` for short, unless you want to coddle IE6 :P EDIT: wait, IE6 doesn't have QSA anyway... :P

Comment: Thanks! Do you think there is any better way of checking for :hover/:active/etc. then checking for whether individual styles are applied?

Comment: Interestingly, `document.querySelectoryAll` seems to accept `:hover` and `:active` pseudo classes (not pseudo elements).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.querySelectorAll(rule)` to get all elements that match your selector, and then check if your element is in there:

```
function isRuleApplied(r, i) {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll(rule);
    for (var j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
        if (all[j] == i) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```